# How have you ever interacted with a Nabaztag?

Tags: http, api, nabaztag

The [Nabaztag](http://www.nabaztag.com/) I ordered has arrived. I know there is an [API to interact with the critter](http://api.nabaztag.com/docs/home.html) from your own software. Have also seen links to libraries in Perl and .NET among others, and have started work myself on a simple .NET Compact Framework 3.5 library for interacting with the bunny from my mobile phone.

I have seen at least one application claiming to interact with the Wifi bunny: [the TFS Build Notification application by Rob Aquila](http://raquila.com/software/team-foundation-server-build-notification-screen/). (Not related to this question, but this does look like a nice app to have running on a central monitor in a large TFS Team...)

I'm just curious to experiences by other people with the Nabaztag:

- Have you ever used the Nabaztag API to interact with wireless rabbits?
- What did you do? Is it freely available to try it out on my bunny?
- How did you like working with the API? Did you just use the HTTP API yourself or did you use a library? And if so, which library did you use?
- Even if you did nothing with the API yourself, what applications and/or websites do you know of that can interact with a Nabaztag?
- Any other tips?

Comment: http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Nabaztag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a CruiseControl.net plugin with it. Had some issues with the default API because it is not that good documented, so needed a lot of experimenting. Furthermore it is not that easy to develop to the default API.

So i made an .net API (c#) which abstracts the violet api away and gives you more help while developing, specially while creating choreographys (pain in butt they are Yoda would say).

Currently both are not available to the general public but i am in the process of releasing.

Things that can be neath to implement on your bunny, i don't know, local traffic information (nice to have) new releases for music you like, interfacing with your phone? (send command from phone to bunny)

Comment: I started my own C# wrapper library as well. It seems every developer with a bunny has done so at some time. ;-)

This effort already includes a tiny - ugly GUI! - Windows Mobile client for letting the bunny speak and getting/setting ear positions and sleep status. Not ready for release either.

Have however been experimenting with this in http://twitter.com/peSHIrTweets: when I use the Fuel function (=interact with FuelFrog.com) my bunny at home says I have filled up the car with petrol again. ;-)

Comment: Released the first version of my C# API today (because my company totally rocks and gave me time to do it). Maybe you could give me some feedback on it? Its located at http://code.google.com/p/q42nabaztagapi

Comment: Have only looked at code, not actually tested it with my bunny yet, but seems to get the job done. It does seem to be rather close to the original API - eg. three numbers to set a color, rather than using a Color value.

I hope to some day complete my own API that should be even easier to use with that respect.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a shameless plug for my employer, but someone wrote a quick and dirty Perl script to make a bunny read out log events from ZXTM (Zeus Extensible Traffic Manager).

- [The Perl script](http://knowledgehub.zeus.com/articles/2008/12/15/zxtms_like_to_tweet_too#c289) (and further up that page, how to plug it into ZXTM)
- [Video of the bunny](http://www.viddler.com/explore/lancew/videos/2/)
- [VMware image of ZXTM](http://www.zeus.com/downloads/desktop/) suitable for use on a desktop to try this out

Answer (score 1):

I extended the start on a python api wrapper that others had made, and have a few apps (ugly control panel, personal weather and traffic reader, Google calendar events of the day).  They are all available for download at [www.mcgurrin.com/nabaztag](http://www.mcgurrin.com/nabaztag).

Answer (score 0):

Hey peSHIr, congrats for getting a rabbit. Now as violet got bought by Mindscape, it's sure it'll continue living...

I would like to develop funny stuff for the rabbit as well, but it seems like a big fuss and it's hard to get started - I checked out several APIs and proxys to get a grip on it - found many projects but either useless or outdated. Although it's written in PHP, the OpenNab Project seems to be one the fewer active around. Maybe worth to check it out?

http://opennab.sourceforge.net/

I hope Mindscape will provide a better API, or even better, open source the rabbit!

Comment: "It's sure it'll continue living..." #right :-(